# Could anyone explain the use of "would" in this sentence

Tags: modal-verbs

> I imagine it would taste mighty good.

Why does this sentence use "would" and not will?

Comment: Out of context, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

It's a question of certainty. "will" implies certainty. In a short timespan you are certainly going to find out that it tastes mighty fine. You Will.

But here the narrator is less certain. He is imagining the food or drink, and there is less certainty. It is possible that it doesn't match his imagination, or that they can't get the ingredients, maybe the store is almost closed?

So: (if all circumstances line up and everything goeds right) I imagine it would tast mighty good.